# Laravel - Eloquent update not working with mutators

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an Event model where i can update start date for an event. I have this for a mutator:

```
protected function setStartAttribute($value)
{
    $date = \Datetime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i:s', $value);
    $this->attributes['start'] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

I need to update a collection of events that have same code, and i call update on those, and i dont get valid date, it enters 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in database, but validation passes.

```
public function putDate($code)
{
    $models = Events::where('code','=',$code);
    $rules = array(
        'start' => 'required|date_format:d.m.Y H:i:s'
        );
    $validate = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validate->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::action('AdminEventsController@getShow', $code)
                    ->withErrors($validate->messages())
                    ->withInput();
    }

    $models->update(array('start' => Input::get('start')));

    setMsg('Saved!');
    return Redirect::action('AdminEventsController@getShow', $code);
}
```

I found a working solution like this:

```
public function putDate($code)
{
    $models = Events::where('code','=',$code)->get();
    $rules = array(
        'start' => 'required|date_format:d.m.Y H:i:s'
        );
    $validate = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validate->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::action('AdminEventsController@getShow', $code)
                    ->withErrors($validate->messages())
                    ->withInput();
    }

    foreach ($models as $model)
    {
        $model->start = Input::get('start');
        $model->save();
    }

    setMsg('Saved!');
    return Redirect::action('AdminEventsController@getShow', $code);
}
```

What is problem in here? Is update method skipping mutator?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that.  Have a look in [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L950) and you'll see...

Comment: I debugged the Eloquent\Model update method, when the $models->update() is called it doesnt even try to call that method, it goes directly to Builder class...very strange.

Comment: Ah, that's because you're working with a query builder there.  If you were to `->get()` the models and iterate over them, calling `->update()` on each (similar to your second code example) then it would work.

Comment: $models = Events::where('code','=',$code);
I think this is Eloquent, not a query builder.

Comment: Well, it's an Eloquent Query Builder rather than a Fluent Query Builder, but many functions fall back on the Fluent Query Builder.  That update that you're looking at is on [Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L225-234)

Comment: Ah, yea, i just noticed that....than i'll use the iteration to update it, thanks for info.

Comment: Laravel 5.4 has the same issue.